# how to contact a service's method from a notification?

Tags: android, service, notifications, broadcast

I am implementing a music player. The notifications allow the user to pause or skip a song.
I use

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.package.app");
mExpandedView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next_song, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0));
```

In order to transmit this click to the MusicService that hosts the MediaPlayer and all the associated methods. I would like to directly call a method part of this service (playNextSong() for example) but `getService()` seems to only allow me to launch a new service, not to call a method in the service, or get some data. I don't even need to launch the service, since the music is playing, it is already running.

So is there a way to do this that I am not aware of ?, or is :
Notification broadcasts to BroadcastReceiver, then BroadcastReceiver broadcasts to the service the recommended way do accomplish this action ?
It looks like a convoluted way to do something simple...

Comment: What is it you try to do? You say "transmit this click to my app". What click? What app?

Comment: @Christine I have edited the question for clarity. Basically I want to call a method that is part of my MusicService from a Notification. I am able to do this by first broadcasting to a MusicBroadcastReceiver; then using it to send a local broadcast to the MusicService. I wonder if I can get rid of the BroadcastReceiver, this his only role is to relay the broadcast. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create PendingIntent for notification as broadcast message, custom one (use your own string like com.my.custom.broadcast.message.action). Create and register in AndroidManifest new broadcast receiver that will be fired by this custom action. OnReceive method of the Broadcast receiver, start your service with custom arguments/action or whatever, based on class of Service and context arguments passed into onReceive method.

Probably you can try to directly start service by creating PendingIntent for that, but I think it is better do it through middle-step: BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Yep, that's what I am doing (and it works). I am wondering whether I can get rid of the BroadcastReceiver : its only role is to relay the broadcast... so it seems a bit useless and inelegant (and a waste of resources) but I have not found a way to directly call the service method yet.

Comment: It is okay to use Broadcast, because it does not take resource at all. Just launched once and call onReceive method, that is Broadcast in general for. So, no worry.

Answer (score 0):

From the Notification you can start an Activity. That activity would do "bindService" and call the appropriate method in the service, then finish(). The activity doesn't need to have a UI, so the user won't see it. But that's even more code than a Broadcastreceiver.